# MongoDB performance slow with C# driver, not in commandline

Tags: c#, performance, mongodb

I'm exploring MongoDB to check if we can/will use it as a noSQL store for our product.
Everything appears to be working fine, but it's rather slow in our C# application. Queries take about 120 to 140ms to return the results, which is unacceptable for our application (more as 10 times slower compared to MS SQL).
At first I thought it might have something to do with the `$in` operator and the `Guid` fields I was filtering on, but this isn't the case.

At the moment I have created a small test to measure the performance of a specific query. The method looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> QueryTest<T>(string collection, IEnumerable<Guid> shouldBeIn, string fieldName)
{
    var dataModelCollection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<T>(collection);
    var findResult = dataModelCollection
                            .FindAll()
                            .ToList();  //Doing this on purpose, so the query is executed immediatly. Just for this test!
                                        //This action takes about 110~140ms.
    return findResult.AsQueryable();
}
```

Obviously this is test code as I wouldn't to a `ToList()` in real code and return an `IQueryable` later on.

When I run this query in the MongoDB console it returns the result in 0ms (according to the explain)

```
> db.StoreData.find().explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 21,
        "nscannedObjects" : 21,
        "nscanned" : 21,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 21,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 21,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "server" : "mymongodbserver:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

There's an index specified at the `_id` field and also one on the `StoreId` field, because I want to filter on the `StoreId` later on.

Both queries, the C# and console, are executed on the same machine. I've also ran the test multiple times and have run the `.reIndex()` command also a couple of times.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

**edit**

It's a very small database with only a little bit of test data/records. As requested, there are **21 records** returned, I think the result of the `explain()` method also tells this.
I've ran the `toArray()` also. I don't see how this will help, but this is part of the result as copying 21 objects in here probably isn't very helpful.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542e847e048b8b0f704a7834"),
        "StoreId" : BinData(3,"/FQLn0k/hkSofM9WvEsNKQ=="),
        "Shelves" : [
                {
                        "ShelveId" : BinData(3,"iCDhfhi6z0adh2haWjrzoQ=="),
                        "Name" : "Shelve 1",
                        "Type" : 0
                }
        ],
        "Doors" : [ ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542e847e048b8b0f704a7835"),
        "StoreId" : BinData(3,"p7TkqeFrGEOAWtv0RZ4YjQ=="),
        "Shelves" : [ ],
        "Doors" : [ ]
},
```

**edit2**

I've added some more data in my `StoreData` collection to see if returning a lot (100.000) documents would be faster or slower.
In the MongoDB client (`mongodb.exe`) I get enormous fast results.

> ```
> > db.StoreData.find().explain()
> {
>         "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
>         "isMultiKey" : false,
>         "n" : 100021,
>         "nscannedObjects" : 100021,
>         "nscanned" : 100021,
>         "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 100021,
>         "nscannedAllPlans" : 100021,
>         "scanAndOrder" : false,
>         "indexOnly" : false,
>         "nYields" : 781,
>         "nChunkSkips" : 0,
>         "millis" : 53,
>         "server" : "cp-crossbario:27017",
>         "filterSet" : false
> }
> ```

As you can see, returning about 100.000 results is happening in **53 milisecconds**.

Running the `FindAll().ToList()` method via the MongoDB driver results in receiving all the document in **5075 miliseconds**. Quite the difference!

A bit more background information on the machines I'm running it on:
I've set up 2 Azure Standard_A2 machines (2 cores, 3.5GB memory) in the region West Europe.

One of the machines is running the MongoDB database. I've installed this on `C:\MongoDB` and the data directory on `C:\MongoDB\bin\data`. This is just for testing purposes. No real production system should install there date on this drive of course.

The testing database is about 135MB in size.

On the other machine I've got the testing clients installed, the console application using the MongoDB C# driver and the MongoDB.exe. Both connect to the database via the same HTTP endpoint.

**edit3**

I've just ran the `QueryTest` method without the `<T>`, so now I'm returning the 'raw' `BsonDocument`s. The weird thing is, it's even slower. The 100.000 documents now take ~8000ms to return, while returning the POCOs they return in ~5000ms.

Comment: How many records are returned ? can you add .toArray() to your console test ?

Comment: Is it possible this is just an artifact of the data deserialization? How does the performance change if you add more items? Are you using compile-time types for the results etc.?

Comment: The data which is received is deserialized to a POCO class which I have created, StoreData. I'll try to do the same with an anonymous class and see what happens.

Comment: Did you find any more information on this subject? I'm testing MongoDB on my machine and I have similar results: (0.5ms) per items, linear. If ask for 100 items == 50ms, 1000 items == 500ms (using C# driver 2.0)

Comment: Sorry for responding so late, @W3Max. I've written my findings in a blog post somewhere in October of 2014. You can find it over here: https://jan-v.nl/post/data-access-for-mongodb Not sure if it's still correct, it's been over 3,5 years now. If someone feels like trying it out and confirm it in an answer below I'll be happy to accept the answer if it contains a code sample of the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your comparison in the shell is that the shell, when run with .explain(), doesn't actually pull back back any data. Effectively, you've eliminated the entire network stack. So the 53 millis you are seeing is how long it takes for the server to iterate over all the data. Since you are running in Azure, I'm quite sure the network will account for the majority of that overhead. You could prove this by running a network capture at the same time and see how long the TCP requests take.

Also, when querying for so many results, MongoDB sends the results in batches. This means that it's not just 1 network round-trip. Rather, it's a number of them, each adding overhead into the timing.

Answer (score 1):

I retrieved 100,000 records in 1411ms, the problem should be something else such as hard failure or ...
If you wanna use it in a foreach loop u can avoid '.ToList()' code an use the result as MongoCursor

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added some more documents in the collection and can see returning 100.000 records via mongodb.exe is blazing fast (53ms), while the C# driver still is slow (~5000ms). This extra information is now added in the post.

Comment: @Disposer is right. While the shell will only return a cursor, over which you have to iterate, toList will load the complete result set to the client, which for obvious reasons takes much longer and will block in the meantime.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg then how would you handle when I need full result set to move further?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Did you ever find out how to handle a full resultset?

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann No. I simply do not do it. If I need the full result set, this is due to aggregations I want to do over it. But for that, MongoDB provides [the aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)